# Hide a JSON field in a response object

Tags: java, json, rest, getjson, jsonresult

Lets say I am using REST based services using JAVA and I have a JSON response object which resembles as shown below.

```
<Response> "some text" <Response>
  <xyz_1> "some text" <xyz_1>
  <abc_action1>  "some text" <abc_action>
  <abc_action2>  "some text" <abc_action>
  <abc_action3>  "some text" <abc_action>
  <abc_action4>  "some text" <abc_action>
<Response> "some text" <Response>
```

In the current implementation the corresponding Java class for this Response Class has 5 instance variables { xyz_1, abc_action1, abc_action2, abc_action3, abc_action4}
 with getter and setter methods

So all  I want to do is depending on the queryParameters of the incoming REST call I want to hide(not emit) one of the tags in the response object. Is this possible as the Java class has 5 variables defined?

Comment: Some parameters applied from `queryParameters` and this parameters you want to hide.

Comment: No depending the values in the queryParameters of the REST call I want to hide the tags(fields) in the response object.

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON at all. And the answer depends on your JSON serializer.

Comment: @JBNizet can you please elaborate on how is this feasible depending on my serializer?

Comment: If I knew what your serializer is, I could read its documentation and find out (you could probably as well).

Answer (score 1):

If you use something like jersey for your REST implementation, then you can use @JsonIgnore to do that task. If you use a different provider, then atleast you can check out the source code and do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a `ResponseDTO` class (DTO as in Data Transfer Object, see this [article](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) for a very brief intro) and have your(*) service return objects of that class instead of `Response` objects. In your service you will be initialising only those fields of your `ResponseDTO` object that are appropriate to the current query parameters.

Or you could be returning a *new*, non-managed `Response` object, where, again, you'll be initialising only those fields that are appropriate to the current query parameters. You should be careful here, not to be making changes to a *managed* Response object, as these changes will be persisted in the database.

(*) "you" and "your" here refer to the *anonymous* "you" and not the OP, who by now must have already figured this out, one way or another.  :)